# How do I replace HTML instead of appending to it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function sethtml(a,b)
{
    document.getElementById("canvas_html_"+a).
innerHTML = "<iframe frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" width="200" height="40" name='innerFrame'></iframe>";

    var objDoc = window.frames[ "innerFrame" ].document;
    objDoc.write(b);
}
```

This just adds b to the iframe and the page just gets bigger and bigger.

Comment: Just cut the objDoc part? And set a src for the iframe?

Comment: @Max0999, `document.getElementById("canvas_html_"+a).outerHTML = "...";` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sethtml(a,b)
{
    document.getElementById("canvas_html_"+a).src=b;
}
```

b being a link to new HTML content.

EDIT:

```
function sethtml(a,b)
{
    var x = document.getElementById("canvas_html_"+a).contentDocument; 
    x.open();
    x.write(b);
    x.close();
}
```

Comment: I need to replace the content of the iframe not the element

Comment: Ok this is what I'm stuck with now: `<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="&lt;input type='text' size='25' value='0' onclick='canvas_html_fire_event(0)' readonly&gt;" width="200" height="40" class="canvas_html" id="canvas_html">
        </iframe>` Still doesn't display it properly

Comment: Try this:
`var x = document.getElementById("canvas_html_"+a).contentDocument;
    x.write(b);`

Comment: Thank you Robin V, now there is some progress as multiple text fields are added to the iframe properly, I want every text field to replace the one before it, so I want every x.write to replace everything in the iframe before it.

Comment: I've edited my main answer. By using the `.open()` method the content is first cleared before you add the new content with the `.write()` method.